# Passing hash arguments from command line in Rspec

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

Need something, which can be work as below to keep rspec DRY:

```
rspec spec/features/users_spec.rb:12 -fd tab: 'Home'
```

Using,

```
ruby 1.9.3
rspec 2.6.4
Rails 3.1.6
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.43.0'
```

In actual, I am having multiple 'it_behaves_like' more than 50 having same repeatative code for multiple combinations as below.

Below is just an basic example to explain my problem :

```
describe 'Login' do

  primary_admin = { acc_type: 'admin', user_type: 'primary' }
  secondary_admin = { acc_type: 'admin', user_type: 'secondary' }
  primary_admin = { acc_type: 'non-admin', user_type: 'primary' }
  secondary_admin = { acc_type: 'non-admin', user_type: 'secondary' }

  tab = { tab: 'Home' }

  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', primary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', secondary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', primary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', secondary_admin.merge(tab)

  tab = { tab: 'My Profile' }

  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', primary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', secondary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', primary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', secondary_admin.merge(tab)

  tab = { tab: 'Security' }

  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', primary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', secondary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', primary_admin.merge(tab)
  it_behaves_like 'Authorized User', secondary_admin.merge(tab)

end
```

For multiple tabs, it will require to repeat same code as above done.

I want to pass 'tab' argument from console, if possible. Please advise, if it is possible or any other way to reduce this repeatative code.

Note: I want to keep these test suits in different parts as above, to pick require test suite easily by using line number when needed.

Comment: If you pass tab via env, you don't need the three sections anymore

Comment: yes, but specific case for that tab can not be executed by line number which was the first aim. That's why I have mentioned it  in Note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use env vars

```
env TAB=home rspec spec/features/users_spec.rb:12
```

Then, in your code

```
tab = { tab: ENV['TAB'] }
```

Comment: I tested `FOO=bar irb` and it doesn't start. I need to use the [env](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) command. I'll edit your question if you don't mind

Comment: I think this is because I'm using Fish shell (it works in Bash), but regardless, I think it's less fail-likely to use `env`.

Comment: `rspec spec/features/users_spec.rb:12 TAB=home` will not work?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i have passed 3-env variables, it works, but can not execute specific case by using line number.

Comment: EMAIL='t@example.com' FLOW=two_stage TAB=home rspec spec/features/users_spec.rb:18 -fd

Comment: in console, displaying as `Run filtered including {:line_number=>18}`
but, it executes all spec from the beginning,

Comment: And what is on line 18?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163047/discussion-between-rhunal-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thanks for your help, it worked. Due to some iterations in shared examples, I was unable to execute by line number. But now I have resolved those iteration issues and able to execute by line number.

Comment: cant we execute as 
 
`rspec spec/features/users_spec.rb:12 TAB=home` ?

Comment: @Rhunal: no, that'd make it a parameter to `rspec` command, not env var (I think)